# SignalR on Mono Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, mono, signal

Had tried to launch SignalR client (.NET Framework 4.5 target) on my Pi 3 with Mono on Raspbian. But it's not working because SignalR's throws a `System.InvalidProgramException` - something wrong with `Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509CertificateCollection` constructor...

> Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException:  --->
>   System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in
>   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509CertificateCollection:.ctor
>   (): method body is empty.

Is there anyone here who has an idea how to fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: Could you get your Mono version and [edit] that into your post? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, @Aurora0001 you're right, thanks!

So, I did only `sudo apt-get install mono-complete` which installed the **Mono 3.2.8** instead the latest version.

I forgot add the Mono repository to my system:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian raspbianjessie main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official.list
sudo apt-get update
```

And after that install the Mono:

```
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
```

And the **Mono 5.2.0** was installed!

[Link](http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-lin-raspbian).

Comment: Note: This installed Version 5.10.1.47 for me, on Raspbian Jessie

Comment: @TheColonel26 yep, cause in Sept '17 the latest version was 5.2.0. You can see latest stable version here http://www.mono-project.com/download