# How to install MonoDevelop or other IDE for Mono 5.2.0 on Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: raspbian, software-development, mono

I have used [this accepted answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/72325/signalr-on-mono-raspbian?newreg=0eb4046ec8234345901d06a7a316c490) to install Mono 5.2.0 to the Raspberry Pi 3. But I don't know how to install monodevelop or other ide to the Rpi3, because sudo apt-get install monodevelop doesn't work anymore because of those settings in the accepted answer. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

i found this link which explains the process i think but i haven't tried it for myself (yet).

you need to add the mono repository using the commands shown (see link) and then you can just do sudo apt-get install monodevelop

https://www.monodevelop.com/download/#fndtn-download-lin-raspbian

hope this helps.

Comment: Just fyi, there is a `raspbianbuster` source, but no `monodevelop` package for it. The latest that the package is available for is `raspbianstretch`, and at least installing MonoDevelop from there and running it initially works fine on Raspbian Buster.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
```

to compile

```
mcs program.cs
```

and to launch

```
mono program.exe
```

Comment: And how would I write an app? I wanted to create the program.cs somehow in Raspberry Pi, but it's a bad idea to write that with a simple text editor.

Comment: so you just want an IDE? What language do you want to develop in?

Comment: Yeah, I thought it's obvious that I want an IDE. I want to develop in C#. My only problem was I can't install Monodevelop in Raspberry with mono 5.2. (as I said, sudo apt-get install monodevelop doesn't work with mono 5.2 installed). 
Now after I successfully reinstalled mono 3.2.8, I could install monodevelop.
It would be good to find an IDE for mono 5.2...

Answer (score 0):

Look for monodevelopment ide (Development Environment for GNOME) in your add/remove software